# USE ELSE 0 doesn't work as expected in SQL

Tags: sql

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    modal_text, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN ab_group = "control" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
FROM 
    onboarding_modals 
GROUP BY 
    1 
ORDER BY 
    1;
```

This doesn't work as expected (it will count more than expected), but when I remove the `ELSE 0` in aggregate function, it works as expected:

```
SELECT 
    modal_text, COUNT(CASE WHEN ab_group = "control" THEN 1  END) 
FROM 
    onboarding_modals 
GROUP BY 
    1 
ORDER BY 
    1;
```

Could someone explain me why having the `ELSE 0` will make it count more data than it should be?

*It will also work if I use `ELSE NULL`

Comment: count counts non-null values, including 0.

Comment: Did you mean to use `COUNT(CASE`... instead of `SUM(CASE`...?

Comment: However, your query is odd in other ways. Which dbms are you using?

Comment: What DBMS are you using? `ab_group IS "control"` seems quite strange

Comment: @DM, I use SQLite, the problem maybe you feel weird is because i use `IS` instead of `=`?

Comment: @derpirscher, I used SQLite, maybe it will not make it become too weired if I used = instead?

Comment: yeah, the `IS` seemed a bit strange but in SQLite it is indeed supported. @jarlh already explained why your first approach didn't work. You can make it work with `SUM(CASE WHEN ab_group = "control" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` though  (ie use SUM instead of COUNT)

Comment: @jarlh, thanks for the mentioning, but why removing the `else` statement, it will count and work as expected?

Comment: @james because if you have no else the result of the `CASE` is also NULL when the condition doesn't match.

Comment: @derpirscher, thanks for the explanation!:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because a `COUNT(SomeColumn)` doesn't count the NULL's in a column.

`COUNT(1)` or `COUNT(*)` count the rows.

And so does a `COUNT(CASE WHEN x=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`
This has no NULL's to ignore, because it's either 1 or 0.

But a `CASE WHEN x=1 THEN 1 END`
is just the implicit shorter syntax for
`CASE WHEN x=1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END`

So it's normal to `COUNT` without the `ELSE`.

```
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN x=1 THEN t.ID END)
```

If you do want to use an `ELSE`, then do it with a `SUM`

```
SUM(CASE WHEN x=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I am become a little bit confused why the `sum` will work as expected,  `The SUM() function returns the total sum of a numeric column. `, but why the 0 value will also be counted (a stupid question, I am new to sql)? I am start to thinking about the difference between `sum` and `count`.

Comment: The value `0` is also counted **because it is a value**. `COUNT(<expr>)` counts non-null values, whatever they are.

Comment: It's as T.I. said.  The SUM of a column or expression also ignores NULL. But 1+0+0+0+0+0=1.  But a COUNT of `(0),(0),(1),(null)` is 3, because there are 3 non-null values.

Comment: @LukStorms, Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Use `SUM()` instead of `COUNT()`, as in:

```
SELECT 
    modal_text, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN ab_group = "control" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
FROM 
    onboarding_modals 
GROUP BY 
    1 
ORDER BY 
    1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, wonder in this situation, is there any difference between them or they work the same?

Comment: `COUNT(<expr>)` count non-null values including zero. `SUM(<expr>)` on the other hand just sums.

Answer (score 1):

> Could someone explain me why having the ELSE 0 will make it count more data than it should be?

Becasue `COUNT(CASE WHEN ab_group = "control" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` is different to `COUNT(CASE WHEN ab_group = "control" THEN 1  END)` let's see a sample below

we can see there will be count when we use `count(1)` or `count(0)` except `count(null)` `count` function will not be count when the value is `null`

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT COUNT(1)

| COUNT(1) |
|----------|
|        1 |


SELECT COUNT(0)

| COUNT(0) |
|----------|
|        1 |

SELECT COUNT(NULL)

| COUNT(NULL) |
|-------------|
|           0 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT SUM(1)

| SUM(1) |
|--------|
|      1 |


SELECT SUM(0)

| SUM(0) |
|--------|
|      0 |

SELECT SUM(NULL)


| SUM(NULL) |
|-----------|
|    (null) |
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/9eecb7/14650/5)**:

Comment: Thanks for the great example!